# invoke a alarm sound when ios app is in background and someone pick it, using core motion

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

invoke a alarm when someone touched the iPhone or iPad and a app is running in background.
this is happening into a ios app i.e. [iAntiTheft](https://apps.apple.com/in/app/iantitheft/id1026601065)
iAntiTheft is not using the location i checked the permission of the app, in a scenario i put the app in background activating motion alert and device get's locked after some time, now i pick the device, it immediately show a Notification and start alarm on high volume.
one More thing here to notice it always playing a low volume beep beep after enabling the motion sensor alert. any help appreciated.

how can i achieve this.

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Comment: i got my answer just one min back

Comment: last line of this question is the answer to get motion alert in the background

Comment: just put a audio in low voice in the background and chill

Answer (score 0):

**The answer to get Core Motion Update when the app is in background and the device locked. in both case just put an audio with background mode playing after the core motion updates function, now the device will go to background or get locked you always getting the core motion coordinates updates**

Repo Link Providing soon